# Targeting m and m/

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to target www.mydomain/m and www.mydomain/m/ for redirecting.

I used to serve mobile-friendly pages out of /m/ directory on my server, using the subdomain m.mydomain.com

I no longer do so and now redirect those requests to the main site, which works fine.

However, a request for /m or /m/ now results in an infinite loop of redirects.

The redirects from the old m.mydomain.com are quite complex, and I need to retain the /m directory on the server.

I have tweaked the relevant parts of .htaccess (in both mydomain.com, m.mydomain.com) by commenting out the directives, but of course, that breaks the main redirects I'm trying to do, and it didn't fix the problem.

This is what the /m directory .htaccess has, and successfully redirects traffic to the main site:

`redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/`

So I'm now trying to just target the requests that produce infinite loops, that is, /m and /m/ and redirect them to the homepage, i.e. www.mydomain.com

I've tried (in the mydomain root .htaccess):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^\/m$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]`

and

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^\/m\/$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]`

I expected these would target the /m and /m/ requests, and redirect to the home page, but the infinite loop continued for both.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules in /m/ directory .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Add this rules in top of your mydomain root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m\/$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^m$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JarekBaran. Your suggestion got me closer, but not quite there. I still needed to redirect all the old pages from /m directory to their new locations (same directory name, same file name).

This is what eventually worked:

In root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In /m directory .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^m$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.intmath.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This now redirects the old m.example.com/directory/page to www.example.com/directory/page, and there is no infinite loop for www.example.com/m